# Xamarin Forms Prism Can't access PCL classes from android project

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I'm using Xamarin Forms Prism and I can't use my PCL classes in android project.
common example : 
here is the Interface in PCL

```
namespace BlankApp.Helpers
{
   public interface IToast
   {
      void MakeLongToast(string msg);
   }
}
```

and here is the class in android project

```
namespace BlankApp2.Droid.DependencyService
{
   public class ToastImp : IToast
   {
   }
}
```

it can not find IToast Interface reference !

there is a suggest from IDE with this msg : "Reference 'projectname-WebAppMAinModule' and use 'projectname.Helpers.IToast' " 
 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbs8W.png)

which does nothing actually ! 
I don't have these kind of problems in XamarinForms I face theme while using Prism . Do I forget something in referencing my PCL ?

I'm using
  **Prism.Forms (7.0.0.396)** 
  **Xamarin.Forms (2.5.0.122203)** 
also there are my project dependencies
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izfgO.png)

Comment: What Prism Version are you using - Let Us See some Code. you'll learn quick that stack overflow users do not like screen shot code. its a form of laziness

Comment: @LeRoy actually there is no code ! I just have problem accessing PCL classes from android project .I also edited the post ;))

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to implement PCL interfaces and use its classes, etc. in your platform specific code (Android included).

Use the following steps:

1. Make sure your Android project is referencing your PCL.
2. Delete your Android obj & bin folders.
3. Recompile your PCL
4. After recompiling your PCL, recompile your Android project

See if it recognizes your interface now.

If the above doesn't work, then as one last option is:

1. Close the solution
2. Re-open the solution

Both of these typically work when your project won't recognize a newly created Interface.